# Import the jersey source code in Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, jersey-client

I'm trying to import the current jersey 2.11 source code into my local eclipse workspace. I have downloaded the source code in zip format from the URL below.
https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.11

Now I'm trying to import it as an existing Maven project. My plan is to modify it and create my own jersey modification.

It will be great if anyone has done it earlier or something similar to this.
Thanks!

Comment: The eclipse import answer is correct below but you should fork a branch of the jersey codebase and then clone that locally if you're planning on committing changes back to the project.

Comment: I did the way you suggested; but I still get compilation errors. I'm looking for someone to help me if anyone has done this Jersey Import as a Maven Project.      Error::                                                                                                                                                                                                             The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library '/Users/VJha/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-common/2.10.5-SNAPSHOT/jersey-common-2.10.5-SNAPSHOT.jar' jersey-client.

Comment: HI emeraldjava! Could you please help.

Comment: humm - your project has a dependency on 2.10.5-SNAPSHOT which assumes you've jersey-common built locally. I'd change this SNAPSHOT version to a jersey-common that you can pull from a public maven repo. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common

Comment: I tried this as well. Right now I'm getting error related to                                       import  org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.LocalizationMessages; imports. The java code is trying to find this particular java file (LocalizationMessages); however I can not find any such file. I'm looking into GIT-Hub as well; but could not find this LocalizationMessages java file. I think if I can get this import error fixed; then my project setup will be complete. Please assist and help me. Thanks.

Comment: Goodness, I made it work. Thanks everyone for the help. I'm in the process of documenting this process and I will upload the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version of Eclipse, importing an existing Maven project is easy:

1. Choose menu *File > Import...*
2. Choose option *Maven > Existing Maven Projects*
   [image]
3. Select the root folder of the repository you downloaded and choose the project you want to import.

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing the same; however I'm getting compilation errors. So I'm looking if anyone has done the Jersey Import using GIT. My understanding is that if I clone the tag from GIT; and then if I import the project as Maven Project in eclipse; then I should not be getting any compilation errors as the project would have correct and valid pom.xml file.